# How to keep hyperlink as it is while copying from one workbook to another using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA, I have a workbook in which a cell has value with hyperlink and I'm trying to copy that cell value along with hyperlink to another workbook e.g. as it is in excel's **keep source format functionality**.

Here is the code:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2) = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2)
```

This code is just moving the value but I need value with its hyperlink.

Comment: Have you tried copy and paste?

Comment: Could you please show me some reference code?..thanks!

Comment: Could you please go back through your previous questions and accept some answers?

Answer (score 0):

Because the statement you use can only transfer the value from one cell to the other.

Actually `Cells(1, 2)` is the same as `Cells(1, 2).Value` by definition so your statement is actually the same as:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value
```

And now it is clear why it only copies the value.

If you want to copy the entire cell you need to use the [Range.Copy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy).